# Get latest album (limit 1) associated with a profile to show in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am rendering partials into my layout and so far so good with everything but I am not sure how I can limit an item. For examples I have albums which shows the albums a user uploads but how can I limit the albums shown on the profile page of the user.

**_albums.html.erb**

```
<%= div_for album do %>
 <h2><% album.title %></h2>
 <%= image_tag album.photo.url(:small) %>
<% end %>
```

Profile **_album.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'albums/album', :collection => @profile.albums %>
```

How can I tell rails to only show the latest album on the profile page and also limit it to just 1 album?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: `<%= render :partial => 'albums/album', :collection => @profile.albums.last %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your render to limit it:

```
<%= render :partial => 'albums/album', :locals => {:album => @profile.albums.last} %>
```

Depending on your sorting, you may need to use `.first` instead.

You can also do this in your controller:

```
@latest_album = Album.where(:profile_id => @profile).last
```

and then

```
<%= render :partial => 'albums/album', :locals => {:album => @latest_album} %>
```

Comment: Looks like that did the job! Thanks